# Выбор элементов списка с помощью селекторов jQuery

Tags: jquery

Меню на сайте имеет подобную структуру:

```
<ul>
<li>
Пункт первый
<ul>
<li>
Подпункт1
</li>
<li>
Подпункт2
</li>
<li>
Подпункт3
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Как мне выбрать Подпункт 1, 2, 3 с помощью селекторов jQuery?

Comment: Уточню вопрос - Пунктов и Подпунктов может быть бесконечное множество!

Comment: обязательно селектором ? а-то есть [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/GAUt8/

Comment: Согласен, слайсом проще эту задачу решить...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примерно так: $('ul ul>li:lt(3)') — это если нужны первые три подпункта любого большого пункта. Или $('ul:first ul>li:lt(3)'), если только в первом

Comment: если не ошибаюсь, $('ul>li:first>ul>li:lt(3)') правильнее, в данном случае лучше прямо детей указывать, а вообще селектор плох как мой, так и ваш, так как родителю хотя бы класс задать нужно, а то, если несколько уровней будет селектор неоднозначен

Comment: ну извиняйте. Исходим из задачи так, как она сформулирована.

Comment: извиняем, так и быть:)

Answer (score -2):

имеет смысл при генерации списков задавать атрибутами уровень элемента и номер, пример у первого уровня задать в у всех data-level=1 а также номера: data-number=1,2,3

и далее использовать метод .Data()